# iOS: How to change Orientation of only one view controller in app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am facing problem in view orientation in my app.

Like

I have two view controller, VC1 and VC2

VC1 have fix landscape orientation.
VC2 have both

VC1 -> VC2 is fine. means when I go from VC1 to VC2, VC2 change its orientation in both landscape and portrait.

But when I comeback to VC1 from VC2(where VC2 in portrait mode), VC1 also is in portrait mode but I want VC1 is in landscape only irrespective of VC2 mode.

Please guys help me. Seeking solution from last 2 days.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the best way is __1.)__ to allow all orientations for your app then __2.)__ to create a custom root-view-controller (navigation or tab-bar or whatever you need) and override the `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` method by returning the top-view-controller or visible-controller's orientation support – I saw many crazy examples about overriding the app-delegate, but you could ignore those concepts, those are not the proper ways to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link for solution

http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-orientations-landscape-orientation-one-view-controller/

In your VC1..

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, write this in AppDelegate.m

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
 return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

Then, For VC1, in which landscape orientation, write this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
 return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
 return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

For VC2, which have both, change masking to All.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
//OR return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically the view-controller-based orientation support in an iOS app is a piece of cake – I did the code in *Swift*, but *ObjC* concept would be totally identical to this.

I have created a quick tutorial with `UINavigationController` but you can convert that to `UITabBarController` by keeping the concept but updating the environment slightly.

### step-1

initially set the orientation support for your app like this:

[image: all possible orientation is supported by default]

### step-2

create a simple `UINavigationController`-based storyboard like this:

[image: that is how it will look at the end]

***NOTE:*** don't worry if it does not say initially `OrientaionSupporterController` (bonus point if you'd spot the consistent typo here!), I will cover that just in the very next step.

### step-3

create a subset of the navigation-controller, like this:

```
import UIKit

// MARK: - Implementation

class OrientaionSupporterController: UINavigationController {

    // MARK: - Active View Controller

    private var activeViewController: UIViewController? {
        get {
            return self.presentedViewController ?? self.topViewController // for possible modal support
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Orientations

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        get {
            return self.activeViewController?.shouldAutorotate ?? true // yes, rotate it, please
        }
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return self.activeViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations ?? .all // default is all possible orientations
    }

}
```

then make sure the that becomes the base class in IB as well:

[image: that is the base class for your navigation-controller from now]

### step-3

create the individual view-controllers with custom orientation support, like e.g. with only *portrait* and *landscape-left* support:

```
import UIKit

// MARK: - Implementation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Orientation

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return [.portrait, .landscapeLeft] // no one find that preactical but works flawlessly
    }

}
```

---

***NOTE:*** you can convert this tutorial anytime with `UITabBarController`, you just need to (obviously) create a subset of the tab-bar-controller and use the `selectedViewController` to get the currently visible one.

---

***NOTE#2:*** obviously you can go much further on this way and you can nest the customised navigation-controllers in the view hierarchy, or if you have multiple `UIWindow` instances in the queue and override the supported orientations there as well for each individual windows (e.g. some support all four orientations, while some other windows does only landscape for e.g. video playback, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Enable all orientation support for project.**

For VC1 Add this line VC1Controller Class

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations { 
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

For VC2 Add this in VC2Controller Class

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations { 
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
```

Comment: that seems only a half-solution.